# Is a linear transformation with non-empty kernel and image intersection necessarily nilpotent?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> (a) Prove or give a counterexample: if
>   $T\colon\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ is a linear transformation such
>   that $\mbox{null}(T)\cap\mbox{range}(T)$ has dimension at least $1$
>   then $T$ is nilpotent.
>
> (b) Prove or give a counterexample: if
>   $T\colon\mathbb{R}^4\to\mathbb{R}^4$ is a linear transformation such
>   that $\mbox{null}(T)\cap\mbox{range}(T)$ has dimension at least $2$
>   then $T$ is nilpotent.

For part (a) consider a transformation $T(x,y,z)=(0,x,z)$. It's obviously linear, $\mbox{null}(T)=Y$ axis and $\mbox{range}(T)=Y\cup Z$ axes, however, it isn't nilpotent, since $T^3(x,y,z)=T^2(0,x,z)=T(0,0,z)=(0,0,z)$.

I believe it is also possible to come up with a counterexample to (b), but can't construct it.

Comment: Range is a span, not union of two subspaces.

Comment: *Hint*: Apply the rank-nullity theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (a), you should write $Y+Z$, not $Y\cup Z$. Apart from that, you are correct, $(0,0,1)$ is a fixed point of the operator so it can't be nilpotent.

**Hint** : For (b) what dimension must both $null(T)$ and $range(T)$ have for it to be possible ?

Then can you see why $null(T) = range(T)$, so $T^2=0$ ?

Comment: Yes, $\mbox{null}(T)=\mbox{range}(T)$ follows from the rank-nullity theorem.